# specialize a template class using a nested name specifier of another template class

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I want to specialize a template class using a nested name specifier of another template class. But the compiler complains that it can't deduce this code. What should I do?

```
template <typename T>
struct convert{ // this is a class in an extern library
                // the guide of this library tells me to specialize 
                // convert to my own class for some features.
    void foo(T&t) {/* do something */}
};

template <typename T>
struct A{
    struct A_sub{ // my class

    };
};

template <typename T>
struct convert<A<T>::A_sub> { // error, compiler can't deduce

};
```

error: class template partial specialization contains a template parameter that cannot be deduced; this partial specialization will never be used [-Wunusable-partial-specialization]

struct convert::A_sub> {

main.cpp:65:19: note: non-deducible template parameter 'T'

template

1 error generated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need typename keyword:

```
struct convert<typename A<T>::A_sub>
```

But it won't help you, because language prevents what you want to do (http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/n4606.pdf temp.deduct.type):

> The non-deduced contexts are:
>
> —(5.1) The nested-name-specifier of a type that was specified using a qualified-id

Imagine situation like this:

```
template <typename T> struct A {
    using C = int;
};
template <typename W> struct Q;
template <typename W> struct Q<typename A<T>::C> { ... };
...
Q<int> q; // which argument T for A should be deduced and how compiler is supposed to guess?
```

Comment: Yes, as far as i know.