# Why parameter deduction doesn't work in this template template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, template-argument-deduction, template-templates

I have following template function which has template template parameter as its argument.

```
template<typename T, 
         template <typename... ELEM> class CONTAINER = std::vector>
void merge(typename CONTAINER<T>::iterator it )
{
   std::cout << *it << std::endl;
}
```

And the following code uses this code.

```
std::vector<int> vector1{1,2,3};
merge<int>(begin(vector1));
```

It works as expected, but when I use

```
merge(begin(vector1));
```

It cannot deduce type of `T`.

I thought that it could deduce type from `std::vector<int>::iterator it;` as `int`.

Why the compiler can't deduce the type?

Comment: suggestion: search for "non-deduced context"

Comment: This question was asked like 3 days ago (and answered): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56626007/specialize-a-template-class-using-a-nested-name-specifier-of-another-template-cl/ .

Comment: He is trying exactly the same thing - trying to deduce type T based by T::iterator type. Which is impossible, both in functions and classes.

Comment: Note that you also aren't deducing `CONTAINER`, but using the default. `std::set<int> set1 {1, 2, 3}; merge<int>(begin(set1));` [fails](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8c7268a8bb01ed9b)

Comment: If you only need to get `int` from `decltype(it)`, then use [`std::iterator_traits<>::value_type`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_traits). E.g. `template <typename Iterator, typename Value = std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type> void merge(Iterator it)`

Comment: @RadosławCybulski ah sorry, now I got it. I does boil down to the same, though imho not enough to flag as duplicate

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I thought that it could deduce type from `std::vector<int>::iterator it;` as int.
>
> Why the compiler can't deduce the type?

No.

The compiler can't: look for "non-deduced context" for more information.

And isn't reasonable expecting a deduction.

Suppose a class as follows

```
template <typename T>
struct foo
 { using type = int; };
```

where the type `type` is **always** `int`; whatever is the `T` type.

And suppose a function as follows

```
template <typename T>
void bar (typename foo<T>::type i)
 { }
```

that receive a `int` value (`typename foo<T>::type` is always `int`).

Which `T` type should be deduced from the following call ?

```
bar(0);
```

Comment: I thought "using type = T" in the foo. So 0 is int so as T is int. Is it impossible for compiler?

Comment: @user150497 the point is that there are infinitely many `T`s such that `foo<T>::type` is `int`. The language is defined so that it doesn't have to make a choice between them.

Comment: @user150497 - The problem isn't that is impossible. The problem (IMHO, obviously) is that is unreasonable. In your specific and particular case the internal type permit to deduce the template parameter. Generally speaking isn't possible and add a rule (anyway questionable) to deduce the type in particular cases would force the compiler to make a lot additional works to look all possible combinations and accept the code only when a single template matches.